# pyqt4 window resize event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

I'm using python3 and pyqt4 and I want some code to run every time my `QMainWindow` is resized.I would like something like this

```
self.window.resized.connect(self.resize)
```

but `resized` is not a builtin function or method.
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 19):

You must override the `resizeEvent` method.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print("resize")
        QtGui.QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why is the line `QtGui.QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)` needed in the function? In pyqt5 this is: `QtWidgets.QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)`.

Comment: @ZF007 When a method is overridden and you don't call the parent method you can remove the default behavior that can cause problems (unless it's an abstract method)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is looking for it, here is a PyQt5 solution. This is pretty much @eyllancesc code, so all thanks goes to them. There are only a few modifications needed for PyQt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print("Window has been resized")
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: According to my research, the best option for adaptive resizing is using resizeEvent like you suggested, thanks